# Python 403 Forbidden Error when sending Requests even with headers

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

As the title above states I am getting a 403 error. The URLs generated are valid, I can print them and then open them in my browser just fine. I get the whole Request Headers and still 403 Forbidden, can someone help me to solve it ?

```py
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    header = {
        "sec-ch-ua": '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="99"',
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36 Edg/99.0.1150.30"
    }
    url="https://www.nadirkitap.com/"
    get = requests.get(url,headers=header)
    
    print(get.status_code)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in the response text - It tells site is protected by cloudflare and you will need to activate JavaScript. Cause `requests` do not deal with this, you could use [`selenium`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/) instead.

#### Example

Includes `BeautifulSoup` object based on `driver.page_source` and prints a list of book titles:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service('PATH TO YOUR CHROMEDRIVER')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get('https://www.nadirkitap.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

print([t['title'] for t in soup.select('a[title]')])
```

#### Output

```
['İkinci el kitap, yeni kitap, dergi, efemera', 'İkinci el kitap, yeni kitap, dergi, efemera', 'İkinci el kitap ve yeni kitap', 'Bilim ve Teknik Kitapları', 'Çizgi Roman Kitapları', 'Çocuk Kitapları', 'Dini Kitaplar', 'Edebiyat Kitapları', 'Ekonomi ve İş Dünyası Kitapları', 'Felsefe Kitapları', 'Hukuk Kitapları', 'Osmanlıca Kitaplar',...]
```

Comment: Sorry for a little late reply, thanks for your kind answer. It's worked perfectly but I forget to select your reply as a answer.

Comment: A faster way might also be possible using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75275395/20443541)